# JDBC PreparedStatemnt MySQLSyntaxErrorException

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I have read previous questions related to my query.Tried making those changes in my existing code.But still getting this error.I have spent 3 hours resolving this,but not able to catch the bug.Please help me with it.

I am using PreparedStatement for sending SQL queries.Below is the query:

```
String getExistingFileEntry = "select * from test "
                                    + " where a = ? and b = ? and date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)"
                                    + "order by id"
                                    + "limit 1";

PreparedStatement pstVerify = null;
            pstVerify = con.prepareStatement(getExistingFileEntry);
            pstVerify.setString(1, a);
            pstVerify.setString(2, b);

            ResultSet rsFirst =null;
            String existingSum = null;
            //execute select SQL statement
                    rsFirst = pstVerify.executeQuery();
```

Getting this error @ rsFirst = pstVerify.executeQuery()

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1
```

I tried running this SQL query on workbench and returns the correct rows.
Can someone please point me where I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Print out your statement before you execute it. Seems you are missing some spaces.

Comment: Thats a good idea next time onwards..Thanks @ByteNudger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your spaces replace this

```
String getExistingFileEntry = "select * from test "
                                    + " where a = ? and b = ? and date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)"
                                    + "order by id"
                                    + "limit 1";
```

by

```
String getExistingFileEntry = "select * from test "
            + " where a = ? and b = ? and date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)"
            + " order by id"
            + " limit 1";
```